# Mondraker crafty Xr, can't find any details about it?

Tags: frames, serial-number

I have recently purchased a mondraker crafty Xr frame, however all the bikes with this name point to the E-bike section. I can't find the specs of the bike so I can buy the parts for it.

Where can I find more about it based on serial number/frame look?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have a 2015 version of this frame which had the following description:

- Mondraker Stealth Evo Forward Geometry frame
- Mondraker Zero Suspension System, 130mm
- RockShox Pike RC Solo Air 150mm fork
- Fox Float CTD BV Performance LV rear shock
- Sram X1 / Race Face Evolve 1x11s drivetrain
- RockShox Reverb Stealth seatpost

https://mondraker.com/storage/resources/faq/path/catalog-2015-20170210133652-en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mtb-check.com/fr/nouveaute-2015-mondraker-crafty-29-pouces/

2015 manufacturer page on webarchive

http://web.archive.org/web/20141229153924/http://www.mondraker.com/15/esp/bikes/crafty-xr/400